# How to write percentage in readme.md file on github when using Latex syntax?

Tags: github, mathjax, readme

I'm trying to put a math expression in README.md file on github. So I followed the docs from github: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/writing-mathematical-expressions

> $$ Probability = 0.689 + 0.392 = 1.081 = 108.1 % $$

[README.md file outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh9HE.jpg)
But as you can see `%` is not showing, because as far as I could've found it's reserved for comments.

Tried with `\%`, `%%` but still nothing. Searched online but not with success

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a problem with this: \% solved it.. Just because there is not a question like this on stackoverflow
So full equation would be: `$$ Probability = 0.689 + 0.392 = 1.081 = 108.1 \\% $$`

Answer (score 0):

```
$$ Probability = 0.689 + 0.392 = 1.081 = 108.1\% $$
```

Comment: That's not working for me, it has to be two `\`, like this; `\\%`